# Registry restriction for certain processes

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, kernel-module

Is it possible to prevent certain processes from opening/reading a specific registry key? A use case for this would be to make it harder to reverse engineer an application.

Comment: Voted to reopen the question. It appears to be perfectly clear, what the OP is asking for, and the existing answer as well as comments to it provide enough evidence. It may still be too broad, but certainly not unclear.

Comment: Honestly I think this is a bad idea... you can do anything and you will never be invincible to reverse-engineering. Maybe you can do it for some time, but invincibility never lasts forever. You're focusing on things outside your reach instead on what really matters, which is actually improving your software for your loyal user-base. Once you release your software to the wide world, its game over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The registry uses the normal Windows access control model, so you can set an security descriptor for a registry key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights

However, the normal Windows security model associates security with a user account, not a process. Any process running under one user's security credentials will have the same access to the registry as any other process on the same account.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, that may be sufficient. When you really do want process-based instead of user-based authentication, you typically end up with something like a windows service that's accessible only to some special "user" account. That service then provides its own authentication mechanism to verify that it's being accessed by the correct process. This is generally still fairly fragile--it typically ends up with a key of some sort embedded in the "right" process, so reverse engineering can find the key and create another process using the same key.

Comment: So there is no way e.g over a Kernel driver? Check if X process wants to use winapi OR wants to read specific registry key, if so return false? Or could I just hide it from certain processes? Thanks

Comment: @Johnny - yes. need call [`CmRegisterCallbackEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-cmregistercallbackex)

Comment: @RbMm thanks Sir, do you know if there is any sample for my purpose?

Comment: @Johnny - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/registry/regfltr